# CRITICAL - file does not exist! error while using perl script to monitor apache logs

Tags: linux, shell, sh, nagios

I am new to perl. I am getting this error :

```
CRITICAL : "file does not exist"
```

when I try to run a script to monitor httpd error log by Nagios.

```
#!/bin/sh
# Created by Brian Weber <brian@bdweber.net> Jan 5, 2012
# check_file_md5s
# Checks the md5sum of a particular file against one stored in a predetermined list.
# No arguments will return usage.
# Please read usage statement for further detail.

# Modeled after / inspired by / replacing check_file_md5s by Stephen Berg, et al.

VERSION=0.1

MD5=`which md5sum`
MD5_LIST="/usr/local/nagios/md5s"


function check_file_md5() {
        if [ -f $ARG ]; then
                if [ `grep $ARG $MD5_LIST | wc -l` -eq 1 ]; then
                        if [ `grep $ARG $MD5_LIST | cut -d\  -f1` = `$MD5 $ARG | cut -d\  -f1` ]; then
                                echo OK
                                exit 0
                        else
                                echo "WARNING - md5sum does not match! Rebuilding so the next check will match."
                                rebuild_md5_list
                                exit 2
                        fi
                else
                        echo "WARNING - md5sum is not in list. Adding for you now."
                        echo `$MD5 $ARG` >> $MD5_LIST
                        exit 1
                fi
        else
                echo "CRITICAL - file does not exist!"
                exit 2
        fi
}

function show_usage() {
        echo ""
        echo "    $0 - plugin for checking arbitrary md5sum against a predetermined list."
        echo "    This list lives at $MD5_LIST"
        echo "    New files need to be added by doing the following command:"
        echo "             $MD5 /path/to/file >> $MD5_LIST"

       echo ""
        echo "    Usage:   $0 /path/to/file"
        echo "             $0 --help"
        echo ""
        echo "    Version: $VERSION"
        echo ""
}

function rebuild_md5_list() {
        MD5_DATE=${MD5_LIST}.`date +%Y%m%d`
        mv $MD5_LIST $MD5_DATE

        for FILE in `cat $MD5_DATE | awk '{ print $2 }' | sort | uniq | xargs`; do
                md5sum ${FILE} >> $MD5_LIST
        done
}

if [ -z "$1" ]; then
        show_usage
        exit 2
fi

case $1 in
        --help)
                show_usage
                exit 0
                ;;
        *)
                ARG=$1
                check_file_md5
                ;;
esac
```

Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: This is shell script, not perl. You can see it in the first line of the code: `#!/bin/sh`.

Comment: And that is not an error, Script is printing that line.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the (correct) comments already posted: You can see from your listing, that the message is displayed, iff $ARG is not a plain file.

BTW, I would suggest outputting the value of $ARG.

Comment: Thanks, and yes it is shell script, as I mentioned I am monitoring error log in nagios so I am expecting the result ok or critical in this case it is always showing critical, but if I run this script on tty result is ok. can you please elaborate more.

Comment: Well, did you  verify that ARG is identical in both cases? For further debugging, I would list the content of the parent directory of $ARG, in particular the access rights. Maybe when running the script under Nagios, the "nagios user" doesn't have permissions to see the directory.